# Linked images (cells copied from other spreadsheets pasted as linked image) do not show in Excel Web Acess Webpart on SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, excel-services, wiki-pages, excel-web-access-webpart

I uploaded Excel file with multiple sheets and a Summary sheet(just another spreadsheet in same file) containing charts and cells pasted as "linked images" from other sheets in a document library in SharePoint. Then I added Excel web access webpart in a wiki page and in its properties gave the designated Print_Area (containing charts and linked images) of the Summary sheet to show.

-Copied cells from a sheet
[image: Copied cells from a sheet]

-Pasted them as Linked image in Progress Report Summary sheet
[image]

-Marked a Print_Area on this sheet
[image]

-Added Excel Webpart (Add webpart->Business Data->Excel Web Access) in page and set its properties
[image]

-Everything shows from the sheet except the Linked images
[image]

Everything shows normal from the spreadsheet's print area except the linked images. They do not appear. However if I just copy these cells from other spreadsheets and paste as a copy and not as linked image it shows on SharePoint page. Is there a workaround because the data updated in one spreadsheet is difficult to be copied again n again to summary sheet i.e. the end use has to update a bunch of data on correlating sheets and it gets updated on the dashboard/summary sheet automatically.

Comment: Please somebody reply .. I really want to know if issue can be resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: @JoannaW_MSFT yes I did. I upvoted it then. But the user/client has rejected it because they say that a bunch of cell references will have certain column width/height and so another cell reference(table) if created underneath the first one can have different no of columns/column width etc which will create problem. I told them i can be solved through some cell merging but they weren't agreeing and so it's officially closed now =)

Comment: @JoannaW_MSFT Suggested solution is to have excel files saved as PDF, upload them to SP and let executives open it up on one click... PDF opens like butter in SP

Answer (score 2):

The linked picture feature is not supported in Excel Online and Excel Web Access web part.

[image]

As a workaround, use cell references instead.

1. In the Summary worksheet, click on a cell and enter “=” in the cell.
   [image]
2. Then, navigate to sheet 2 “Scope”, select the first cell of your data and press “Enter”. (Demo: column-A, row-1) 
   [image]
3. Back to Summary sheet, pull down +. Other data in column A will also be visible.
   [image]
4. Repeat step 1-4 for other columns.

Using the cell references, Summary sheet will automatically get updates from Scope sheet. And it also works using Excel Web Access web part and Excel Online.

Comment: For user/client it can cause problem like if a bunch of cell references(table) are placed they will have certain no of columns/column width/height and so another cell reference(table) if created underneath the first one can have different no of columns/column width etc which will create problem i.e. upper table having say has 5 columns and separate table under it has 7 columns of varied column widths. I think this issue is more related to formatting and probably can be resolved through cell merging, i am not sure.